# Find $g(f)$ given $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

This may be a trivial problem and I am sorry if it had been asked before.

Given two known functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ I want to find $g(f)$. My first idea was to use the chain rule

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial f}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial f}$$

where the first derivative on the right hand side is easy, while the second  $\partial x/\partial f=(\partial f/\partial x)^{-1}$. This yields $\partial g/\partial f$ as a function of $x$. I presume that I want $\partial g/\partial f$ as a function of $f$, and then integrating to get $g(f)$. Am I on the right track?

Edit 1: These two functions arise from experiments and calculations in thermodynamics. We can approximate $f(x)$ well with the Sigmoid function

$$f(x)=\dfrac{a}{1+\exp({x-x_{0}})}.$$

Experimentally determined $g(x)$ can be approximated sufficiently by the parabola
  $$g(x)=b(x-x_{0})^2+c.$$

The domain of these functions is the vicinity of $x_{0}$, roughly speaking.

Comment: Why can you not compose the two functions together?

Comment: What is $g(f)$? You mean $g\circ f$? And, what about the domain of each function? What kind of functions are they?

Comment: @PeterForeman By composing you mean $g∘f$? Won't this result in a function of $x$?

Comment: @drabus What exactly do you want? Do you need a representation of $g$ in terms of the function/variable $f$?

Comment: @PeterForeman Yes, exactly that. Might have to do it numerically in the end. I have two sets of experimental/calculated data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $f$ is invertible with inverse $f^{-1}$ we have that
$$g(x)=g(f^{-1}(f(x)))=(g\circ f^{-1})(f(x))$$
and hence the function $g\circ f^{-1}$ provides $g$ in terms of $f$. In your example you have
$$f^{-1}(x)=x_0+\ln{\left(\frac{a}x-1\right)}$$
and hence we get
\begin{align}
g(x)
&=(g\circ f^{-1})(f(x))\\
&=b\left(x_0+\ln{\left(\frac{a}{f(x)}-1\right)}-x_0\right)^2+c\\
&=b\ln^2{\left(\frac{a}{f(x)}-1\right)}+c\\
\end{align}